# redirection 301 htaccess not working for other urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used these lines on htaccess file to redirect www.example.com/* and ww.example.com/* to ww1.example.com/* The problem is the home page are redirected but the other urls like www.example.com/url-content or ww.example.com/url-content redirection doesn't work to ww1.example.com/url-content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ww1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Not sure what the “pattern” `^` would actually match; guess it could perhaps match _only_ the empty string when `/` was requested. Try `RewriteRule . https://…` instead.

Comment: I tried this : RewriteEngine on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ww1\.example\.com$
RewriteRule . https:// ww1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301] Still not working :/

Comment: You are missing an `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` so processing will continue through the file (and possibly conflicting with other directives). Do you have other directives? Otherwise, the rule you posted should work as intended.

Comment: @CBroe `^` doesn't actually _match_ anything, but it is _always_ successful - which is all that's required here.